# How can i extract the the sharpest and clearest design from this block?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, opencv

I want to extract the design present in the image. I have used Skimage library to first add gaussian blur and then use sobel filter to extract edges to get the design . However,the output image is not sharper and has noise .How can i get a sharper and clean image of just the design. I have attached two images, first one is the original grayscale image and the second one is processed image.

original image:

[image: the original image].

Processed image:

[image: Processed image]

The resultant image :

[image: The resultant image should be somewhat close to this picture. Maybe we can thin those edges and remove all the noise]

Comment: How do you expect the answer to look please?

Comment: Thanks for being interested ,i have attached the resultant image

Comment: Are you scanning these yourself? You should probably look into a 3D scanner, which would make this problem trivial.

Answer (score 1):

@RahulVerma looks pretty tough from first principles. The external edges should be pretty easy with Gaussian + Sobel + Canny. The inside is a mess due to uneven lighting and surfaces. I'm thinking shape index, but I expect that it will also be quite noisy. In your place I would try a machine learning based tool like [Ilastik](http://ilastik.org).

Comment: Thanks ,Will check  out IIastik